# Iterate over list of dicts in order of property

Tags: python, sorting

Consider a list of `dict`s with a `date` property and an `amount` property:

```
transactions = [
    {'date': '2013-05-12', 'amount': 1723},
    {'date': '2013-07-23', 'amount': 4523},
    {'date': '2013-02-01', 'amount': 2984},
]
```

I would like to add a balance property, but to do so I must iterate over the list in `date` order:

```
balance = 0
for t in transactsions:    # Order by date
    balance += t['amount']
    t['balance'] = balance
```

How would one go about this? If I were to replace the `dicts` with `Transaction` objects having `date` and `amount` properties, would it then be possible?

Comment: Yes, Steve! I did find that in the sidebar after posting, but searching did not uncover it. I'll therefore leave this question here to possibly help in searches.

Comment: You can't close it anymore.  I have no idea why people are bothering to answer, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both is possible with "key" keyword argument of function sorted(). Take a look at the snippet:

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 2]
>>> sorted(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x**2)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: -x)
[3, 2, 1]
```

You can pass a callable as "key" keyword argument to sorted() and the callable will be used to provide a sorting key. For your first problem you could wrap transactions in sorted and pass lambda x: x['date] as a "key". For objects just change "key" to something like lambda x: x.date .

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice example of the power of the `sorted()` function.

Comment: Then mark as answered :)

Comment: I had this tab open with the intention of marking, of course! I usually wait a few hours as other answers trickle in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050/343302):

```
for t in sorted(transactions, key=lambda k: k['date']):
    balance += t['amount']
    t['balance'] = balance
```

Funny how searching did not lead to that answer, but after posting it appears at the top of the sidebar!

Answer (score 0):

Careful, you have a typo in your loop (transactsion)

```
transactions.sort(key=lambda x:x['date'])
for t in transactions:
    balance += t['amount']
    t['balance'] = balance
```

This should do the trick, and this way your list remain sorted

Comment: Perhaps that is Python2? In Python3 that throws a TypeError. I don't have Python2 here to test, and I did not specify which Python version in the question as I did not think that it mattered.

Comment: `.sort()` is an in-place sort function for lists, not dicts, as they are inherently not sorted.

Comment: No, you're right. Sort modify the list in place but can't be used here. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Updated.@SteveP., we don't want to sort the dict, what we do is sorting the list of dict so sort can be used.